# how to display the name after the user inputted it

Tags: android, database, fragment

How to display the name after the user has inputted the data and how to make it a button that i can add something there making it something like a profile i want you add a alarm inside it but first i got to make this database.

i dont really know how to how to fix it i tried this code but it doesnt work or it always resulted to a force close when i try to add a
name = edtName.getText().toString();

AccountInfo a = new AccountInfo(name);

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private EditText edtName;
    private Button btnAdd;
    Spinner spin1;
    Spinner spin2;
    Spinner spin3;


    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.bar);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        edtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);

        spin1 = findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrequency);
        spin2 = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTime);
        spin3 = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerQty);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        String  name = edtName.getText().toString();


        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        /*screen*/
        adapter.AddFragment(new Drugfragment(), "Drug");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Appointmentfragment(), "Appointment");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

       /* DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        AccountInfo a = new AccountInfo(name);
        mDBHlpr.insertRecord(a);


        String account_just_inserted = mDBHlpr.getAccountName();
        Log.d(
                "ACCOUNT INSERTED",
                "The Name of the account just inserted is :-" + account_just_inserted
        );*/



        final Account c = new Account();
        if(c==null) {

        }else{
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("LOG IN");
            LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.account,null));
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();


                                    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.accountname,null));
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                        }
                                    });


                                    builder.show();
                                }
                            });



            builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });

            builder.show();


        }

    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    }
```

MAINACTIVITY

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private EditText edtName;
    private Button btnAdd;
    Spinner spin1;
    Spinner spin2;
    Spinner spin3;

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.bar);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        edtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);

        spin1 = findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrequency);
        spin2 = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTime);
        spin3 = findViewById(R.id.SpinnerQty);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);



        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        /*screen*/
        adapter.AddFragment(new Drugfragment(), "Drug");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Appointmentfragment(), "Appointment");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

       /* DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        AccountInfo a = new AccountInfo(name);
        mDBHlpr.insertRecord(a);


        String account_just_inserted = mDBHlpr.getAccountName();
        Log.d(
                "ACCOUNT INSERTED",
                "The Name of the account just inserted is :-" + account_just_inserted
        );*/



        final Account c = new Account();
        if(c==null) {

        }else{
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("LOG IN");
            LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.account,null));
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();


                                    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.accountname,null));
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                        }
                                    });


                                    builder.show();
                                }
                            });



            builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });

            builder.show();


        }

    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    }
```

Comment: sorry sir already edited it

Comment: `name = edtName.getText().toString();` – I don't see this line anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: already added it sir

Comment: It would seem that the `<EditText>` with ID `edtName` is not in the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: i put it in drugfragment

Comment: Then you should be handling it in the `Fragment`, not in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textwatcher for this , it will change your name String every time when text is changing in EditText field.

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              name = edtName.getText().toString();

    //it will change your name String every time when text is changing in EditText fiels
            }
        });
```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Its rather simple. On vb.net is just this... c# is only slightly different.

```
    Dim b As New Button
    b.text = "New Button"
    b.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf handle_click

    Private Sub handle_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     'code here to react to the buttons click.
    End Sub
```

Here's a link with lots of info .. Hope it helps
[Controls in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: whats dim in java?

Comment: I don't use java but I think you can ignore that..
b Button;
should work

Comment: The question is about Java, not VB.Net or C#. Post code in Java, or you're not answering the question asked. If you don't use Java at all, and don't know the language, you shouldn't be posting code to answer a Java question.

Comment: Yeah.. I got that after looking at his code closer.. sorry.